# How to view the content of the <returns> tag?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, xml-documentation

In Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express, whenever I create a function, and use the 3 slashes to create the help code, I get something like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Function to sum 2 numbers.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="foo">First number.</param>
/// <param name="bar">Second number.</param>
/// <returns>The sum of the numbers.</returns>
public int foobar( int foo, int bar )
{
    return foo + bar;
}
```

I know that whenever I want to know what a function does, I can hover my mouse over it, and the tooltip shows the text written between the `<summary>` tags.

Also, whenever I open the parentheses to write the parameters of the function I'm calling, I see the tooltip below the cursor which displays the text written between the `<param name="foo">` tags.

So, my question is: Can I view the text written between the `<returns>` tags without having to go to definition and view it in the code it's written in? And if so, how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can view it in `View >> Object Browser`.

Apart from this you do not see it anywhere else. 
In case you would like to present the "return" information via a tooltip then it is better to put it inside the `<summary>` itself as a part of the description.
There are some possibilities to make the `<summary>` more readeable when you want to put more text inside, e.g. by using `<para>`:

```
///<summary>
///<para>line1</para>
///<para>line2 (e.g. what a method returns)</para>
///</summary>
```

Comment: I agree, but keep in mind however that this causes documentation generators like docfx to not properly place the information in their "Returns" sections then, which may be unwanted.